# this suport libary should not use a lower version (21) than the target SDK 23

Tags: android, gradle

In my `build.gradle` file I am getting this warning,

```
this suport libary should not use a lower version (21) than the target SDK 23
```

I currently have

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "20.0.0"

defaultConfig {
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 13
    versionName "1.7"
```

And then

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: 'Parse-*.jar')
I get the error on the line below
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.2'
compile 'com.parse.bolts:bolts-android:1.1.4'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
compile project(':facebook')
```

}

How can I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Change:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.2'
```

to:

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.1'
```

so that the major version number of the support library (23) matches your `compileSdkVersion` (23).

Comment: Thanks you, just so I know how do u know what number to put there, I get that the 23 is my compile SDK but how do I know if its 23.0.1 or 23.1.1 and such?

Comment: @spenf10: Personally, I look in my Android SDK. `$ANDROID_HOME/extras/android/m2repository/com/android/support/support-v13/` will show the different versions of `support-v13` available in your local Android Support Repository (where `$ANDROID_HOME` is where you installed your SDK).

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:21.0.2'
```

to

```
compile 'com.android.support:support-v13:23.1.0'
```

And your change your BuildToolsVersion to `buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"`. The numbers may differ (23.0.1 / 23.1.1), according to the version of the **Android Support Library** that you've installed.